# How do I enable nested virtualization on a Windows Server 2012

Tags: server, ansible, configuration, devops

I am trying to setup Configuration Management using Ansible, I'm running Windows Server 2012 and I need to setup a VM instance of Linux or Ubuntu and install virtual box again within the Ubuntu VM. for this to work I need to enable nested virtualization on the Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

you can enable this feature, by using the following command in an administrative PowerShell terminal,the VMName in the command is the name of your VM Instance.

```
Set-VMProcessor -VMName VMName -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```